# Nilpotents after tensoring with a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A \to B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings with unit. Let $A_{\text{red}}=A/ \sqrt{(0)}$ and $B_{\text{red}}=B/ \sqrt{(0)}$ be the corresponding reduced rings. Now let $A_{\text{red}} \to K$ be a ring homomorphism to a field $K$ (of characteristic zero if you want). This gives us a (surjective) homomorphism of $K$-algebras $B \otimes_A K \to B_{\text{red}} \otimes_{A_{\text{red}}} K$.

Now my question: Is every element of the kernel of this map a nilpotent?

If it fails for arbitrary $A$, is it perhaps true when $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over a field of characteristic zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General fact: Let $B,C$ be $A$-algebras and $I$ an ideal of $B$. Then $$B/I \otimes_A C = (B \otimes_A C)/ \langle i \otimes c : i \in I, c \in C \rangle.$$This is an easy consequence of the universal properties involved. Specifically, you can use these to construct homomorphisms in both directions which are inverse to each other. Alternatively, you can also use the Yoneda Lemma to give a one-line proof.

In your situation, $B_{\text{red}} \otimes_{A_{\text{red}}} K = B_{\text{red}} \otimes_A K$ is the quotient ring of $B \otimes_A K$ by the ideal generated by elements of the form $i \otimes k$ with $i \in B$ nilpotent. But then $i \otimes k$ is nilpotent, too.

Comment: May the downvoter please explain what this answer is missing?

Comment: hi martin, I'm happy with your answer so far. But I'm also curious why you've been downvoted.